# React native 0.64.0 incompatibility with CocoaPods 1.10.0 when running pod install

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

While running `pod install`, this error appeared:

> React native 0.64.0 [!] `React` requires CocoaPods version `>= 1.10.1`, which is not satisfied by your current version, `1.10.0`

Using:

- React native version: 0.64.4
- CocoaPods version: 1.10.0

Answer (score 6):

Resolved by updating CocoaPods to the latest version.

Use this command: `sudo gem install cocoapods`